# "Comma expected after operand 1" when defining a series of bytes in NASM?

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16

According to NASM's documentation, the following allows me to define 64,000 uninitialized bytes at the label `Vid`:

```
Vid resb 64000
```

According to subsequent documentation, *this* should allow me to initialize those bytes to 0xFF instead:

```
Vid db 64000 dup (FFh)
```

This, however, yields the error `error: comma expected after operand 1`.

I have also tried:

- Adding a colon after the symbol name `Vid`
- Using `0` or a question mark for the default value instead of FF (although FF is my intended value)
- Using smaller numbers of bytes, such as `64`
- Adjusting capitalization
- Rearranging my source file so that this directive appears in different sections, etc.
- Adding commas between 64000, dup, and (FFh) - which obviously does not work

I cannot find *anything* online suggesting that this syntax has changed or that there are any cases where it should not work.

As important background, I am compiling to a `bin` file and have the `cpu 8086` directive in my source.

Comment: No idea where you found `dup` in the nasm documentation. That is masm syntax. [nasm uses `times`](https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.08/html/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.2.5)

Comment: @Jester section 3.2.1 [here](https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html). I'm guessing the gotcha is "starting in NASM 2.15", since that version seems to be less than a year old.

Comment: Nice! That's what I get for having the link to old manual cached by the browser. So then the question becomes, is Ethan using a new enough nasm version?

Comment: That's the same error message I get from nasm 2.14.02.  So indeed, the answer seems to be "upgrade, or use the TIMES syntax."

Comment: @hobbs That's the documentation I was looking at, indeed I should have been using TIMES on my version!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting comment to answer: `DUP` was only added to NASM with version 2.15 (released in June 2020). For compatibility with older versions, use [TIMES](https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.2.5), e.g. `times 64000 db 0xff`.